# How outsystems manage to develop a iOS mobile application in its P10 version without Mac and Xcode

Tags: outsystems

How Out System guys are managing to develop a iOS mobile application in its P10 version without Mac and Xcode. It is given in their link https://success.outsystems.com/Documentation/10/Getting_Started/New_in_OutSystems_10 that it doesn't need Xcode. How ?

Comment: Maybe ask them?

Answer (score 1):

OutSystems uses Xcode to build apps for iOS, it just doesn't require *the user* to have such tools.

This is because the app packages that you submit to the app store are built on the [MABS](https://www.outsystems.com/blog/posts/how-mobile-apps-build-service-works/) remote service. MABS itself will use Mac OS X and Xcode, removing the need for OutSystems' customers to have those. You can see [more details on MABS architecture here](https://medium.com/outsystems-engineering/our-silver-lining-building-mobile-apps-using-amazon-web-services-45c255337d01).

Comment: Thank You for the great Info.

Answer (score 0):

There is no xcode or Java (Android) programming involved at all. What you are building in Outsystems is a hybrid mobile application. More info about Hybrid Mobile Applications you can find here: https://developer.telerik.com/featured/what-is-a-hybrid-mobile-app/

Summarized, what Outsystems is doing is the same as what Phonegap/Cordova can do. You built a web application (HTML, CSS & Javascript) and with Phonegap/Cordova you make it possible to make use of some mobile "native" functionality through javascript. When you generate the mobile app Outsystems creates a shell around this web application code, so that it is a .APK or .IPA file (Phonegap/Cordova does do exactly the same).